# Head pointer in stack pop function crashes program

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, crash, stack

I've been trying to find this error everywhere folks, i dont know where i messed up. I am writing a program that reads in text, pushes parenthesis into a linked list stack, and pops them back out when a matching parenthesis gets read in. However, upon the pop function, it crashes.

The problem either lies in my pop() or my push() function.

```
void IntStack::push(int data){
    assert(!isFull());
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
}

int IntStack::pop(){
    int result = -1;
    if(isEmpty()){
        result = head->data; //Crashes on this line
        Node *temp;
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The following is the driver.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include "IntStack.h"

 using namespace std;

 bool ArePair(int first,char last){
     if(first == '(' && last == ')') return true;
     else if(first == '{' && last == '}') return true;
     else if(first == '[' && last==']') return true;
     return false;
 }

 int main(){
     string fileName;

     cout << "Hello, please enter a filename: ";
     cin >> fileName;

     ifstream inFile;

     inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

     while (!inFile){
         cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open " << fileName << ". Please re-enter.\n";
         cin >> fileName;
         inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
     }

     string current;
     IntStack iStack;
     int par; //parenthesis

     while(inFile){
        inFile >> current;

        for(int i=0;i<current.length();i++){
             if(current[i] == '('||current[i] == '{'||current[i] == '['){
                 par = current[i];
                 iStack.push(par);
                }
             else if(current[i] == ')'||current[i] == '}'||current[i] == ']'){
                 if(!iStack.isEmpty() || !ArePair(par,current[i])){
                     cout << "debug\n";
                 }
                 else{
                    iStack.pop();
                 }
             }
         }
     }



     inFile.close();

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I think it might be an invalid pointer.. although im far too inexperienced to be able to tell. I understand this is not the most efficient way to utilize a stack, but its for a class that requires i use a singly linked list. The end of the code is incomplete as i never got passed my pop function.

EDIT: The rest of the code is as follows.

```
bool IntStack::isFull(){
    return false;

}
bool IntStack::isEmpty(){
    if(head == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```